# Получать значения по ключу

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent

Проблемка такая, передаю в intent два значения для одного ключа:

```
    val allowIntent = Intent(this, PaymentIntentService::class.java)
    allowIntent.putExtra("button", true)
    val serviceAllowIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, allowIntent, 0)

    val cancelIntent = Intent(this, PaymentIntentService::class.java)
    cancelIntent.putExtra("button", false)
    val serviceCancelIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, cancelIntent, 0)
```

После чего место где получаю эти значения, пытаюсь вызвать метод `getSessionData()`, но увы до него он не доходит, так как почему то getBooleanExtra() работает не совсем корректно, а именно не находит значения по ключу button:

```
if (intent.extras != null) {
        if (intent.extras.containsKey("button") && intent.extras.containsKey("sessionSecret")) {
            allow = intent.getBooleanExtra("button", true)
            getSessionData()
        }
    } else cancelNotification()
```

Возможно потому что я проверяю сначало intent.extras а потом работаю с getBooleanExtra() не знаю, но альтернатив получать нужные мне значения по ключу я пока не вижу.

Comment: Возможно, а если сразу проверять `intent.hasExtra("button") && intent.hasExtra("sessionSecret")`, не трогая `extras` ?

Comment: Интересно. Можно понасоздавать явные интенты с одинаковым ключом, но с разными значениями, а потом встречать в одном месте эти значения по этому ключу? Или я что-то недопонимаю, просветите пжл.

Comment: А как вы передаете и принимаете интенты?

Comment: @TimurVI Ну что то из рубрики, ну меня интересуют два значения, поэтому собственно идеально сочетается.

Comment: Используйте нормальное значение для флага последнем параметром при создании `PendingIntent`. Например, `PendingIntent.getService(this, 1, allowIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);`

Comment: @rjhdby что конкретно не понятно? я вроде описал и передачу и получение.

Comment: @eugeneek а вот это интересно.